# What do these arp commands mean?

Tags: networking, router, arp

Now and then my router displays the following error message in the browser:

> This function is to prevent the attack was interrupted when you use the Internet.
>
> Please install to download ARP binding.
>
> This feature will be automatically discharged after you shut down.

And then asks me to run the following commands:

```
arp -d
arp -s 192.168.1.1 00-17-16-03-37-21
```

I've checked `man arp` but I can't quite tell what it does. Any idea what the commands above mean, and whether I should actually run then?

Comment: It appears you have more than one device on your LAN that thinks its IP address is `192.168.1.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This message looks suspicious.

The two commands are asking you to flush the ARP cache (arp -d), and to set as your IP address 192.168.1.1 a pc whose MAC address is 00:17:16:03:37:21

ARP (Address Resolution Protocol) is a key protocol in LANs, helping to associate a MAC address to an IP address (who has 192.168.1.17? Tell 192.168.1.1...). Technically, it translates the network addresses into link layer addresses. This is of utmost importance in networks with many clients (Multiple Access Networks), like LANs.

The commands are asking to throw away what your router has learned, in favor of a new association between MAC address and IP number. It might very well be a trap.

One thing first: is this the **exact** error message you have seen? Or is it somehow your rough recollection? I am asking this because this error message is extremely poor English, and, if it is the exact message, then the chances of it being bogus are really very high.

Second, the vendor associated with this MAC address (00:17:16) is QnoTechn, a Chinese manufacturer without a proper Web page, according to a Google Search. It may be legitimate.

Third, you can establish whether the message is bogus by checking the MAC address of known, legitimate pcs and routers on your LAN. The commands *ipconfig* (Windows) and *ifconfig* (Linux+Mac) [notice the small, critical difference between the two commands] will give you, among other things, the MAC address of all NICs (=Network Interface Card) on your pcs. You ought to check them against 00-17-16-03-37-21, and see who has it.

If no one does, then the message is **surely** bogus, and you have an unseen client to your network (wireless, most likely, if you are at home). If a pc has it, then that pc has been infected. If the router has it (you can check it from the router's GUI), then it might be genuine.

In any case, I would **not** follow the advice. Turning the router on and off will instead clear the problem, for the moment at least. You should then start to read about securing your network, because the problem will not simply vanish.